# Unable to center cell values on a table using pd.style

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe

***Context:*** I have a dataframe I want to display on streamlit and I'd like to center the cell values (they're at the right by default for some reason). For that, I've been trying to use `pd.df.style.set_table_styles` and `set_properties` to center the cell values but no luck so far. They seem to work for some of the alterations, but centering the values just doesn't work for some odd reason.

***Minimal reproducible example:***

```
th_props = [
  ('font-size', '14px'),
  ('text-align', 'left'),
  ('font-weight', 'bold'),
  ('color', '#6d6d6d'),
  ('background-color', '#eeeeef'),
  ('border','1px solid #eeeeef'),
  #('padding','12px 35px')
]

td_props = [
  ('font-size', '14px'),
  ('text-align', 'center'),
]

cell_hover_props = [  # for row hover use <tr> instead of <td>
    ('background-color', '#eeeeef')
]

headers_props = [
    ('text-align','center'),
    ('font-size','1.1em')
]
#dict(selector='th:not(.index_name)',props=headers_props)

styles = [
    dict(selector="th", props=th_props),
    dict(selector="td", props=td_props),
    dict(selector="td:hover",props=cell_hover_props),
    # dict(selector='th.col_heading',props=headers_props),
    dict(selector='th.col_heading.level0',props=headers_props),
    dict(selector='th.col_heading.level1',props=td_props)
]

    arrays = [
        ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
        ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],
    ]
    tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=[None, "Brand"])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns=index)
    
    # table
    df=df.style.set_table_styles(styles,overwrite=False).set_properties(**{'text-align':'center'})
    st.table(df)
```

***Current output:***

The table currently looks like this:

[image: ![image|690x84](upload://4TvfcGa4uAJXYd0cpX50tyOozS2.png)]

As you can see, I'm able to modify the table and even align the row indices all the way to the left, but I can't find the way to center the cell values (and the headers/columns as well for that matter!)

I also know this is working and changing the HTML properties because when I pass the style object to_html() (`st.write(df.style.set_table_styles(styles).to_html())` ) and render the HTML output, I get something like this:

[image]

As you can see, HTML sees that text-align: center is being used. For some reason, streamlit is not capable of passing these properties to the table..

How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting to `st.markdown` from Streamlit instead of `st.table` and transforming into html using `to_html()` solved the issue. Here's an example (using the styles on the question above):

```
arrays = [
    ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
    ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],
]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=[None, "Brand"])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns=index)

st.markdown(df.style.set_table_styles(styles).to_html(),unsafe_allow_html=True)
```